# How to get the max value from database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tbl_app");
$sql="SELECT MAX(tokenno) AS max FROM tbl_order";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);    

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
$tokenaabselect=$row['max'];
echo $tokenaabselect;
```

**Database Design:**

```
id   name  tokenno      
------------------
1     ram     1
2     harry   2
3     sam     6
4     ham     7
5     san     8
6     nan     9
7     hell    10
```

I am trying to get the maximum value from the database and i am running above code.

Now the problem, I am getting from this code is it select maximum value from `tokenno` as 9 where as  it have to select maximum value as 10.

I don't know if the maximum value from database is 8 than it works but when maximum value on database is 10 than it select 9 or 8 the single digit highest value. I don't know what is the problem.

Please help me to select maximum value 10 from the database. Looking for positive response.

Comment: Is it a numeric column, or varchar?

Comment: Mario its a varchar column.

Comment: You colum type is string not int

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the datatype of column  tokenno is varchar or char. Change it to decimal or convert the value to decimal in your query.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(tokenno AS DECIMAL(10)) AS max FROM tbl_order
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change you data type to **int** i think you datatype is string type

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of datatype of tokenno. Make sure the datatype for tokenno in your DB is not a varchar, make sure it is int for integer.